# Sending large content over Network

Tags: haskell

so I want to send huge stuff via tcp, therefore I use the Network.Socket library...

First of all I have a wrapper data type (Example!):

```
data Message =
        List [Int]
    |   String String
    |   END
    deriving stock Generic
    deriving anyclass Binary
    deriving Show
    deriving Eq
```

so a normal work-pipeline would be:

```
--client
let bytestring = encode $ List [1..1000000] -- Lazzy ByteString
send socket $ toStrict bytestring
--server
Just msg <- recv socket 1024 
print $ decode $ fromStrict msg
```

the problem with this is: I get the following error:

> Data.Binary.Get.runGet at position 1017: not enough bytes CallStack
> (from HasCallStack):   error, called at
> libraries/binary/src/Data/Binary/Get.hs:351:5 in
> binary-0.8.8.0:Data.Binary.Get ClientProjekt: Network.Socket.sendBuf:
> resource vanished (Broken pipe)

Allthough

- just sending/reciving and printing without decoding on the server works fine.
- encoding -> toStrict -> fromStrict -> decoding: without sending over tcp works fine.

so what does the network do with the bytestring which breaks the decoding functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that `recv socket 1024` requests only 1024 bytes from the socket, so the received message is being truncated.  Also `send` doesn't actually guarantee that the full bytestring will be sent.  You want to use `sendAll` instead.

I'd advise using `sendAll` and `getContents` from `Network.Socket.ByteString.Lazy` to avoid converting your lazy bytestring to and from a strict bytestring and to save you the trouble of manually writing a `recv` loop.  A minimal server might look like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Binary
import Network.Socket
import Network.Socket.ByteString.Lazy
import Prelude hiding (getContents)

data Message = List [Int]
  deriving (Generic, Binary)

main = do
  let hints = defaultHints
        { addrFlags = [AI_NUMERICHOST, AI_NUMERICSERV]
        , addrSocketType = Stream }
  addr:_ <- getAddrInfo (Just hints) (Just "127.0.0.1") (Just "8080")
  s <- socket (addrFamily addr) (addrSocketType addr) (addrProtocol addr)
  bind s (addrAddress addr)
  listen s 1
  (s', _) <- accept s
  List xs <- decode <$> getContents s'
  close s'
  print $ sum xs
```

and a matching minimal client might look like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Binary
import Network.Socket
import Network.Socket.ByteString.Lazy

data Message = List [Int]
  deriving (Generic, Binary)

main = do
  let hints = defaultHints
        { addrFlags = [AI_NUMERICHOST, AI_NUMERICSERV]
        , addrSocketType = Stream }
  addr:_ <- getAddrInfo (Just hints) (Just "127.0.0.1") (Just "8080")
  s <- socket (addrFamily addr) (addrSocketType addr) (addrProtocol addr)
  connect s (addrAddress addr)
  sendAll s (encode (List [1..1000000]))
  close s
```